# How to get latitude and longitude in Android phone?

Tags: java, android, api, mobile

I'm beginning in Android programming and I want to get the longitude and latitude of my Android phone, but I read that the Google Longitude API was discontinued. How I can do that now?

Answer (score 3):

Google Longitude was something else.  The location API uses LocationManager and has never been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. Below code gets the location details from NETWORK_PROVIDER. You can use GPS_PROVIDER if you want to get more frequent updates.

```
    LocationManager locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener loclistener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
            Double lon = (double) (location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,10000,100,loclistener);
```

Source: Code pulled up from my app which is under development.